# How can I show the received image using C#?

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, tcp

I am having both C# application and C++ application. In C++ application, I am capturing the desktop screen as BITMAP and sending the images to C# application through TCP socket. I can send the captured image over TCP, but I can't show the received image in C# application. Kindly see the code:

In C++ application, code used for sending image ([How can I convert BITMAPINFOHEADER into Byte array using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185663/how-can-i-convert-bitmapinfoheader-into-byte-array-using-c)):

send(theSocket, (char*)&bi, sizeof(bi), 0);
send(theSocket, lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, 0);

In C# application:

```
private void startListening()
    {
        int port = 0;
        port = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Server is starting...");
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

        Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        newsock.Bind(ipep);
        newsock.Listen(10);
        label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label1.Text = "Waiting for a client...";
        });


        Socket client = newsock.Accept();
        IPEndPoint newclient = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;

        label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            label1.Text = "Connected to client. Recieving image...";
        });

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                data = ReceiveVarData(client);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
                {

                    bytesRead = ms.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                            pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                pictureBox1.Image = img;
                                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                            });
                        }
                        catch (ArgumentException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("something broke");
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (data.Length == 0)
                    newsock.Listen(10);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.Close();
            });
        }

        client.Close();
        newsock.Close();
    }


 private byte[] ReceiveVarData(Socket client)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int recv;
        byte[] datasize = new byte[4];
        byte[] data=null;
        try
        {
            recv = client.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize, 0);
            int dataleft = size;
            data = new byte[size];
            while (total < size)
            {
                recv = client.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
                if (recv == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                total += recv;
                dataleft -= recv;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Client disconnected.");
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.Close();
            });
        }
        return data;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var t = new Thread(startListening);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Have you gone through with a debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: while converting the received data into image there occurs an exception 'Parameter is not valid' on this line of code "Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);"

Comment: Put that in the question, along with anything else your debugger told you/anything relating to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

.NET won't read a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` from a stream. It expects stream data to match normal file formats, but `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is strictly an in-memory format. You would need to include a `BITMAPFILEHEADER` (immediately preceding the `BITMAPINFOHEADER`) as part of your stream, to successfully present a BMP file format stream that .NET would be able to handle.

That said, I wouldn't recommend that if you can at all help it. It would be much better for you to compress the image data by encoding it in a well-known file format, such as PNG or JPEG. This will address the encoding issue, while at the same time significantly reducing the amount of data you're transmitting (and thus improving the latency of your transmission). Presumably on your C++ side, you have access to some image-handling library that can generate PNG or JPEG data for you.

Comment: Checked with adding BITMAPFILEHEADER into the C++ application, now the code is like below:

'send(theSocket, (char*)&bfh, sizeof(bfh), 0);  // BITMAPFILEHEADER
send(theSocket, (char*)&bi, sizeof(bi), 0);  // BITMAPINFOHEADER
send(theSocket, lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, 0);  // buffer for 'bits' from bitmap'.

Still, the same exception is happening, any idea?

Comment: @JithinJose: without a good [mcve], no ideas. I do note that your receiving code seems to be expecting an `int` length prefix, which you haven't mentioned sending. And the receiving code doesn't verify that it's actually read the 4 bytes needed before trying to process it (for that usage, you would be better off using `BinaryReader`). There are lots of ways to get this wrong, and only one way to get it right. So even if I point out the flaws in the information you shared, you haven't shared enough to know whether _all_ the flaws are known.

Comment: Kindly download my Sample projects for both Server application (C#) and Client application (C++) from https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4t0trywwma9p7h/RemoteScreenProjects.zip?dl=0

And please provide your feedback.

Comment: @Jithin: I'm afraid you've misunderstood the Stack Overflow model. All assistance is provided on a volunteer basis, with the expectation that people requesting assistance will provide all necessary information on the Stack Overflow site itself, and limit all code to a good [mcve], posted in their question. Based on the information you provided in your question, my answer above suffices. But if you can improve your question above so that it meets those standards, I'm happy to take a look. See also [ask], and make sure you read the articles linked at the end of that page.

Comment: I think the problem is on the receiver end. Because the client is sending the image like this:
'send(theSocket, (char*)&bfh, sizeof(bfh), 0);

Comment: Here size is the third parameter and at the server end we just getting some values in the receiving buffer and assumes that it is the size of the image. So while converting that values we get an exception 'Overflow occurred'. So how can I know the size of the image coming from the socket?? because I am processing rest of data depending on this size.